# Transfer Exact Same Object Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I brought another question

I have a class Server:

```
package server;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import objects.Player;

public class Servidor implements Runnable, Observer {

int puerto;
public DefaultListModel<Player> players = new DefaultListModel<>();
public ArrayList<Socket> clients = new ArrayList<>();

public static Send m;

public Servidor(int puerto, Send m) {
    this.m = m;
    this.m.addObserver(this);
    this.puerto = puerto;
    System.out.println(this.m + " from the server")
}

@Override
public void run() {
    ServerSocket servidor = null;
    Socket sc = null;
    ObjectOutputStream output;

    try {
        servidor = new ServerSocket(puerto);
        System.out.println("Server Started");

        while (true) {
            sc = servidor.accept();
            System.out.println("New Cliente");

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());

            output.writeObject(m);
            clientes.add(sc);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}

public void Send_Players() throws IOException {
    for (Socket sc : clients) {
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());

        output.writeObject(players);
    }
}

@Override
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    //Stuff
}
```

Then I have my client class:

```
package server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import objects.Player;

public class Client extends Observable implements Runnable {

String host;
int puerto;
Socket sc;

public Client(int purto, String host) {
    this.puerto = purto;
    this.host = host;

    try {
        sc = new Socket(host, puerto);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    DataInputStream in;
    ObjectInputStream input = null;
    DefaultListModel<Player> players = new DefaultListModel<>();
    try {
        in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
        input = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    while (true) {
        Object objeto = null;
        try {
            objeto = input.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (objeto != null) {
            System.out.println("Is: " + objeto.getClass().getName());
            if (objeto instanceof DefaultListModel) {

                players = (DefaultListModel<Player>) objeto;

                this.setChanged();
                this.notifyObservers(players);
                this.clearChanged();
            } else {
                Send m = (Send) objeto;

                this.setChanged();
                this.notifyObservers(m);
                this.clearChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And also the Send class:

```
package server;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Observable;

public class Send extends Observable implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void Send_(Object arg){
    this.setChanged();
    this.notifyObservers(arg);
    this.clearChanged();
}
}
```

Now I will explain how it works:

1. When I create a server I add it to be an observer of the class Send
2. When I create a new Client the server detects it
3. When a new client has came. It sends an object of type, Send.
4. In the client class it detects with the observable that something has came and notify a class named Main.
5. When the observer of the class Main gets notified it do this:

   ```
   this.m = (Send) arg;
   System.out.println(this.m + " from the class Main");
   ```

But class Send from the Server is not equal to the class Send from the class Main
But I need to them to be equal so I can use the Send_ method in the class send to  notify the observer

Output:
server.Send@6576a5d6 from server
Server startes
New Client
Es: server.Send
Sipili
server.Send@156ecdb0 from client

and I need that the first line of output(Object 1)
needs to be the same as the last line of the output

Note: I think that is something to do with the serialized version

Comment: What is the question here? What do you mean by 'class is not equal'? Are you getting an exception? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: no im talking like the class isn't the same instance, Ex: a static variable is always the same, but a non-static variable is different when you create a new one

Comment: When you do this: ExampleClass class = new Class, you created a new class. when you print the class, like this: System.out.println(class);, It prints something like this ExampleClass@8483de6 the end numbers are there because you can create mulriple classes of that type, So they can be different and each one uses their own variables. When I create it from my Server class it is like this: Send@138nf5, but when I use the ObjectOutputStream it dosn't send this: Send@138nf5, it sends a new class so I can't use the variables from that class

Comment: No. Please correct your terminology. You have a terminal confusion between classes and objects (or instances). When you do `new ExampleClass()` you create a new *object* of type `ExampleClass`. `ObjectOutputStream` sends what you tell it to send, but it is *received* as a new object, unless it has already been sent and you haven't used `reset()` or `writeUnshared()`, in which case it gives you back the existing object, but in that case of course without any changes that may have been made at the sending end. Unclear what you're really asking here.

Comment: Yes, Im refering that as an Object. And no, When I send the Object, it creates a new, how do I know it? By simply using System.out.println(), and it prints 2 different objects in the 2 different clases

Comment: That's what I said. But your `System.out.println()`s don't prove anything. There is no reason why objects in different JVMs should have the same `toString()` result if it hasn't been overridden.

Comment: Yes is always the same the output, I've printed the same Object from 2 different clases and in the 2 they were the same, but the object that I've transfer by ObjectOutputStream is different.

Comment: 'From 2 different classes` is irrelevant. I said 'different JVMs'. But this is *all* irrelevant. Serialization delivers new objects, with the exception I described above. What you 'need', you can't have.

Comment: Do you know what sockets do, and what ObjectInputStream/OutputStream do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly you can't, in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html it says that the way it works is by.

1. Sending the object type.
2. Creating the new Object.
3. Replacing the values with the ones that are on your other class.

So it's impossible to do an exact copy.